# Making identical mirrored character strings identical in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

Thank you in advance for any help with this issue.

I am currently conducting an analysis where we are looking at pairwise differences between insect groups. However I have run into a frustrating issue that I can't seem to fix without hundreds of lines of code.

For example, we have pairwise comparisons as characters, which were constructed from two columns `group1` and `group2` using `paste` but this results in mirrored groups i.e. `A_B` and `B_A`.

Does anyone know a solution so we can make these both `bee_beetle`? Or rather a different function to make our pairwise groups.

Here is a quick example...

`df=cbind.data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"),c("B","A","D","C"))
colnames(df)=c("Group1","Group2")
paste(df$Group1,df$Group2,sep="_")`

`"A_B" "B_A" "C_D" "D_C"`

But I would like `"A_B","A_B","C_D","C_D"` irrespective of which group (1 or 2)

We have about 400 odd groupings that we need to normalise.

Thanks again

Liam

Comment: Laim, welcome to SO! This question is too vague to get a meaningful answer. Please read about how to ask good questions, especially parts about sample data, code you've tried (and why it doesn't work), and what is your expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Apologises, I have added a quick example to make the question better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given very little information but if you would like to make sure beetle_bee is bee_beetle, you can try having an alphabetical sort after you split the string by the underscore, and then reassemble.

```
paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(x = "beetle_bee",split = "_"))),collapse="_")
#[1] "bee_beetle"
```

strsplit will split `"beetle_bee"` into a list where the first list contains `"beetle","bee"`. To sort that alphabetically, I remove the list with `unlist`, and then `sort`. I then paste collapse the result back together.

**EDIT:**

```
df=cbind.data.frame(c("A","B","C","D"),c("B","A","D","C"))
colnames(df)=c("Group1","Group2")
apply(df[,c("Group1","Group2")], MARGIN = 1, function(x){
  paste(sort(x), collapse = "_")
})
#[1] "A_B" "A_B" "C_D" "C_D"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response Evan, however we need to do this across a few hundred groups but will use this solution if I need to :)

Comment: Please see my edit now that you have provided more clarity in your question.

Comment: It now uses the apply function with MARGIN = 1, meaning, for each row, sort and combine the groups.